# How to return just Date Created, not Date and Time?

Tags: vba, excel

I Have a line in my code

```
Cells(i,3).value = File.DateCreated
```

And it prints the date created but also the time. Is there a simple change so it prints just the date and not the time too?

I am aware there are other commands DateModified and DateAccessed but am unaware of any for just the date created?

Comment: Do you mean you want to actually *strip* the time part from the value, or you just want to format the cell?

Comment: Try `Cells(i,3).value = Fix(File.DateCreated)`

Comment: I Have tried using =LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-9) in excel but unfortunately this doesn't work as the cells are formatted in date and time format so it just prints jibberish numbers. I was hoping to strip the date part in vba if it is possible?

Comment: I have tried your line Fadi but the macro takes about 3 mins to run, I shall report back if it works then :) thanks in the meantime for the help guys!

Comment: Yep, that worked Fadi! Thank you so much. So that I learn though, what does Fix() do to the command?

Comment: How about: `Format(File.DateCreated, "dd mmm yy")`

Comment: date and time is stored as double number the integer part is the date and `FIX function` extract this part only, see [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Int-Fix-Functions-5446da0c-fbdc-425f-a818-7e3153984ff8)

Comment: Alex This is why vba confuses me lol :) It works but it actually produces the date in dd/mm/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yy. Which is fine because i need the full year but why does it do this? would i not have to write: Format(File.DateCreated, "dd mmm yyyy")

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with that Fadi! Very kind and helpful of you :)

Comment: @IIJHFII, You are Welcome.

Comment: @IIJHFII: Formatting often has its own lexicon. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx)